# Usando o find no angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou estudando angular e estou com um problema.

Criei uma diretiva chamada acao, estou tentando pegar dentro dela o click no elemento ul > li, porém ela não funciona usando o find e eu não posso colocar ng-click porque pode conter N tags...

> Exemplo de como estou chamando

```
//Exemplo de criação do bind do click
$element.find("ul li").bind('click', function(){
   console.log(this);
});
```

> Obs: se eu coloco o bind somente no ul funciona.

Comment: Isso é jQuery, não? Que versão? O `bind` já está defasado.

Comment: Não não é jquery! O $element é uma variável que crio no link da diretiva, eu apenas coloco o nome dela de $element.

Comment: Mas [o angular usa jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), não?

Comment: No site do angular fala que o .bind é do jqLite, porém esta nas documentações do angular.

Comment: Isso, usa o jqLite foi o que eu vi agora. Mais mesmo assim porque ele não consegue navegar entre os elementos dessa forma?

Comment: Parece ser um find limitado. Tentou só `$element.find("li").bind(...)`?

Comment: Ele não encontra com o find('li'), agora se eu uso ele fora do link da diretiva funciona ( agular.element('body').find('ul li') )

Comment: Se você coloca o `bind` no `<ul>` e funciona, provavelmente é porque os `<li>` não foram criados nesse momento ainda. Ou então são recriados depois. É melhor deixar no `<ul>`. Você pode pegar o elemento clicado do mesmo jeito (use `function(e) { var clicado = e.target; /* etc */ }` no bind).

Comment: Faz sentido, o li é um ng-repeat.

Comment: angular não trabalha utilizando sizzle.

Comment: sizzle, oque é isso @Luan Fagundes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar ng-click dentro de um ng-repeat sim, mantenha a function fora do objeto que você passa pro ng-repeat e passe os dados necessarios para ela por

```
 $scope.lista = [{item1},{item2},{item3}];

 $scope.acao = function(index){
    var item = $scope.lista[index]; //valor selecionado  }

 <ul ng-repeat="item in lista">    
   <li ng-click="acao($index)"></li> 
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução, que eu particularmente prefiro, é a utilização de uma função existente somente no escopo da diretiva, desse modo você não precisa fazer "alguns fix", "hacks" ou pior, depender de uma função de um `controller` - que vai completamente contra o propósito de um `directive`.

Apenas faça uma definição de uma função dentro da diretiva e atribua ao elemento através de um `ngClick`, veja:

```
.directive('acao', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.meuClick = function() {
                console.log('rodou');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

E em seu html:

```
<ul acao>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="meuClick()"></li> //ngRepeat somente de exemplo
</ul>
```

Por que usar deste modelo?

Você tem maior controle e melhor manutenção sobre o código. Imagine que futuramente você precise mudar a estrutura de ul/li para div/span, por exemplo, ou que você mude o local onde a diretiva é definida. Deste modo você não precisa rever toda a estrutura do código no directive, verificar se ele precisa de um novo find, etc..

Você aplica o click diretamente no elemento que você precisa e somente dentro do escopo da diretiva, o que não interfere nos demais.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o atributo `acao` em cada `li` no `ng-repeat`, assim você pode tratar os cliques nos elementos.

```js
angular.module("exemplo", [])
.controller("exemplo", function() {
  this.letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
})
.directive("acao", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.on("click", function() {
        // do something!
        alert("You clicked at: " + elem.text());
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";

.clickable-li {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

.clickable-ul {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="exemplo">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="exemplo as ctrl">
    <p>Ação em cada 'li'</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="clickable-li" ng-repeat="letter in ctrl.letters" ng-bind="letter" acao></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```